# Hide Entire PivotTable with VBA Makro

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

i just need a macro, which hides an entire PivotTable.
PivotTable  name = PivotTable4

Thanks in Advance

Greetz

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Average of Server Respond Time")
For x = 3 To .PivotItems.Count
    If Left(.PivotItems(x).Value, 1) = "1" Then
         .PivotItems(x).Visible = False
    End If
Next x
End With
```

I tried this, to delete 1 column after another

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Average of Server Respond Time")
    For x = 3 To .PivotItems.Count
        If Left(.PivotItems(x).Value, 1) = "1" Then
             .PivotItems(x).Visible = False
        End If
    Next x
End With

Comment: So, what's the problem with the code? What is the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
Dim PT As PivotTable
Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

'hide whole rows
PT.TableRange2.EntireRow.Hidden = True
'or hide whole columns
PT.TableRang2.EntireColumn.hidden = true
'or clear
PT.TableRang2.clear
```